# Script to pass the user information to another Jsp page using button click

Tags: html, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm a beginner and looking for help 
I have a query related to posting a user_id on to Jsp page. 
Designing an application to book a photographer where if I click on book for a photographer I should get the photographer details in the next jsp page.

```
<input type="submit" name="book" value="<%=rs.getInt("id")%> onclick="javascript:window.location='booking.jsp';"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append `user_id` in jsp url like following:

```
javascript:window.location='booking.jsp?user_id=<%=rs.getInt("id")%>'
```

And you can get the `user_id` on `booking.jsp` by calling

```
request.getParameter("user_id");
```